# UWP Cannot Resolve ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2015, uwp

i have a problem with my project in visual studio 2015:

In XAML of UWP

```
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
```

*Cannot resolve ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush*

I tried removing and reinstalling visual studio 2015, the Windows SDK, reinstalled Windows 10, however, each new project this error.

However, when I compile the project this works perfectly.

The problem is in the design phase because the window is transparent without background.

EDIT

```
<Page
    x:Class="CineBase.Pagine.Home"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <TextBlock x:Uid="Greeting" Text="" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

this is the full code, the error does not have an identification code.

Comment: To which control you are setting the background? Can you share more code around that line?

Comment: to a grid, but it also happens when I create a new UWP project without changing anything

Comment: That's weird, works perfectly for me.. You could try performing a full uninstall of VS 2015 (personally I recommend using its uninstaller, then uninstalling related programs using Control Panel, then cleaning the rest using [this tool](https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller/releases) to get rid of VS 2015) and then installing VS 2017 that has been released today.

Comment: But it's still weird that even after full reinstallation of windows and everything it doesn't work.. Do you have installed every Windows SDK 10240, 10586 and 14393?

Comment: Is very strange, I just finished installing vs2017 but I've not solved, now I'll try to install the previous sdk 10240 and 10586. At first I thought it was Windows Insider Preview the problem then I reinstalled windows AU but nothing. If it does not work either so I'll try to uninstall everything with the cleaning tool. Thank you so much.

Comment: I am having this exact same issue, this has been happening to me along with other weird glitches such as Error HRESULT_EFAIL randomly. I have never gotten it fixed, with all my attempts

Comment: Hi, I have fixed this problem with a reinstallation of windows 10 AU (not restoring from Settings, but a fully formatted intallation) and new installation of Visual Studio 2017, this is the only way I could find to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I have fixed this problem with a reinstallation of windows 10 AU (not restoring from Settings, but a fully formatted intallation) and new installation of Visual Studio 2017, this is the only way I could find to solve the problem.